# injecting variables into functions; python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-decorators

I have a webdriver class that assumes there is only one driver. This is bad because it can't handle multiple pages at once. I want to make a decorator that will inject `self.driver` into any function decorated if it exists, if not it will allow any function to use the driver passed to it. I should be able to define and function as

```
@get_driver
def this_func(**kwargs):
    #I have access to 'driver' if I have self.driver or if a driver kwarg was given
```

Here it is:

```
import os, time, subprocess, random

from functools import wraps

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

class get_driver(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        wraps(func)(self)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            kwargs.update({'driver': self.driver})
        except:
            pass
        return_ = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return return_

class WebdriverChauffuer(object):

    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None, start_url=None):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.start_url = start_url

    @get_driver
    def source_code(self, **kwargs):
        return driver.page_source or None

class FirefoxDriver(WebdriverChauffuer):

    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None, start_url=None, driver=None):
        super(FirefoxDriver, self).__init__(username=username, password=password, start_url=start_url)

    def start_driver(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I am getting a strange error that no args were given, even though I call `source_code` on an instance, which should give it self:

```
In [1]: from my_scripting_library import *

In [2]: d = FirefoxDriver()

In [3]: d.start
d.start_driver  d.start_url     

In [3]: d.start_driver()

In [4]: d.get('https://google.com')

In [5]: d.source_code()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7419cf5df019> in <module>()
----> 1 d.source_code()

/home/cchilders/scripts/my_scripting_library/webdriver/general.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     24         except:
     25             pass
---> 26         return_ = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
     27         return return_
     28 

TypeError: source_code() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

There's no difference when I change the return to

```
return_ = self.func(**kwargs)
```

Why can't I call `source_code` anymore? Thank you

EDIT:

These drivers are to be used for purposes of course, here's an example:

```
class HCCDriver(FirefoxDriver):

    def __init__(self, init=False):
        super(HCCDriver, self).__init__(start_url="https://hccadvisor.hccfl.edu")

    def main_page(self):
        self.get('https://www.hccfl.edu/hawknet.aspx')

    def login_webadvisor(self, username="cchilders", password="miley_cirus_is_great_singer", driver=None):
        self.webadvisor_driver = FirefoxDriver()
        webadvisor_driver.get(self.start_url)
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.access_link(search_text="Log In")
        driver.find_box_and_fill(search_text="LABELID_USER_NAME", value=username)
        driver.find_box_and_fill(search_text="CURR.PWD", value=password)
        driver.submit_form(search_text="SUBMIT")
        driver.access_link(search_text="Students")

    def login_email(self):
        self.start_driver()
        self.get("http://outlook.com/hawkmail.hccfl.edu")
        # WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox'))
        self.find_box_and_fill(search_text="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox", value="cchilders@hawkmail.hccfl.edu")
        self.find_box_and_fill(search_text="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PasswordTextBox", value="i_love_honey_booboo")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.submit_form("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SubmitButton")

    def login_myhcc(self):
        driver = FirefoxDriver()
        driver.get("https://hcc.instructure.com")
        time.sleep(5)
        find_box_and_fill('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox', 'cchilders@hawkmail.hccfl.edu')
        driver.find_box_and_fill('ctl00_ContentPlawebadvisor_urlceHolder1_PasswordTextBox', 'if_evolution_was_real_americans_would_stop_worshipping_pres_candidates')
        driver.click_button('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$SubmitButton')
```

The point is, without a decorator, I foresaw every single function looking like:

```
def this_func(self, driver=None):
    if not driver:
        try:
            driver = self.driver
        except:
            raise Exception('There is no driver my good sir')
```

with the `driver=None` and

```
    try:
        driver = self.driver
    except:
        raise Exception('There is no driver good sir')
```

parts being repetitive 20, 30 times, etc

Comment: where is `self.driver` assigned?

Comment: In `kwargs.update({'driver': self.driver})` there is no `self.driver` but since you catch all exceptions, you suppress that fact.

Comment: Most people would refactor the offending class to take a `driver` parameter and to change the global references to driver into `self.driver`. You are refactoring anyway to add the decorator, why not just fix the code?

Comment: Are you saying it'd be best to make a new instance of this webdriver class, and only allow FirefoxDriver to have one driver (`self.driver`), instead of having multiple drivers per FirefoxDriver? Because that's how I had it originally (FirefoxDriver always initialized one `self.driver`)

Comment: The issue is I use this as subclasses for bigger classes. What you're saying is these bigger classes could make instances of FirefoxDriver instead of subclassing FirefoxDriver...look at my edit above

Comment: I think Mr. Delaney is right here, and the FirefoxDriver should be a machine, with the specifics (my school robot, resume robot, etc) being like taxi drivers, making a new driver (or browser instance you could say) for each purpose. That way the class running the driver isn't reliant on how the driver works

Answer (score 1):

Because your decorator is implemented as a class rather than a function, your decorated `source_code` function is not being wrapped in a bound `method` descriptor, since this is done to functions, not classes.

That means when you call `self.func`, no `self` argument is being passed in. But your `source_code` method expects a `self` argument, which results in the error `source_code() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

On more recent versions of Python 3 you should be getting `foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. I'm not sure when they added that clarified message.

The comments have given you some ideas about different approaches, but that explains your error.

Comment: so is refactoring to a normal function decorator likely to solve this problem? I'd still like to implement it to understand even if it isn't efficient in this case

Comment: A function-based decorator should work. If you want to deep dive and have time, read https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/tree/master/blog